# adding custom php function to xsl

Tags: php, xslt

I've got a custom function say `<?php this_content('Main heading'); ?>` and I want to add inside my xsl, which looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="page" mode="body">

</xsl:template>
```

I've set registerPHPFunctions(), but thats only for php internal functions..?

Comment: Have you configured Apache (or your webserver) to have PHP process .xsl files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it works for functions you've defined, too. Make sure that you've added the php namespace to your opening XSL tag as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
```

Then you can call your PHP functions using `php:function('function_name', ...)`.

(You can't just embed blocks of PHP code like you would in a .php file.)

See the examples and comments on [the PHP man page for registerPHPFunctions()](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php) for more info.